# Magento 2.0.7 - password rules

Tags: magento2, password

my project is build on magento 2.0.7. Do you know what are the customer password rules? I can not find the Number of Required Character Classes, Maximum Login  Failures to Lockout Account, Minimum Password Length on customer configuration, like magento 2.2.x has.

Thank you all

Comment: in magento 2.1 store->configuration->customer->customer configuration -> password option there  u can select hope this is same as 2.0.7

Comment: ssatish4u, in magento 2.0.7 I can not see those options